# Using a custom renderer in XPiNC fails

Tags: xpages, xpinc

I followed Sven's hint, how to implement empty html5 attritutes to xpages: [XPages: Empty HTML5 Attibutes & PassThroughTags](http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=2049)
I works very well in browser clients.

But when I open that peace of code as an XPiNC I always get this error message in trace-log-0:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot find class ch.hasselba.xpages.PassThroughTagRendererEx in NSF
```

I played around with different package names, build paths. But even if I can find the compiled class on the expected place under WebContent/WEB-Inf/classes, I get this error.

When I strip down all functionality, the class cannot be found:

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages;

import com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.PassThroughTagRenderer;

public class PassThroughTagRendererEx extends PassThroughTagRenderer {
    // I don't do anything!
}
```

The faces-config.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <render-kit>
    <renderer>
      <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
      <renderer-type>com.ibm.xsp.PassThroughTagRenderer</renderer-type>
      <renderer-class>ch.hasselba.xpages.PassThroughTagRendererEx</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
  </render-kit>
  <!--AUTOGEN-START-BUILDER: Automatically generated by IBM Domino Designer.     Do not modify.-->
  <!--AUTOGEN-END-BUILDER: End of automatically generated section-->
</faces-config>
```

Is it possible at all to implement custom renderers in XPiNC applications?

Comment: Using custom renderers in XPiNC applications is possible. Maybe something other is wrong with your app. Is it a local db or on a server?

Answer (score 1):

After a complete reinstall of the IBM Domino Designer 9.0.1FP3 w/o any additional Extension Library or other plugins custom renderers do work in Client.